# What is the simplest way to securely access my Raspi from internet?

Tags: ssh, vpn

Either from my laptop or my andoid tablet
I thought first Port forwarding and the pair of keys for SSH would be good but no avail I lost myself..
Thinking that it's easier I tried also Openvpn but I did not succeed either. Moreover Openvpn seems much for my personal use ?
I am looking for an advice
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

OpenSSH is designed to be the most secure way to tunnel into your machine.

When I say tunnel, I mean connect into the console via an encrypted tunnel, where you can also connect using SFTP over port 22, reroute local ports into you machine to make it look as if you were at the machine while surfing somewhere else in the world, redirect X application but in its simplest form, log into the console as root or another user.

It depends what you want to to connect to the raspi? View webpages as if you were inside the LAN? So no port 80 forwarded to the internet? [It takes some configuring but look at this tutorial.](http://howto.ccs.neu.edu/howto/windows/ssh-port-tunneling-with-putty/) Basically the client creates a proxy at your local(outside from home) and anything you want to access your remote(the machine at home) goes via the poxy, into the tunnel and get routed on the Pi.

At the least you need to open port 22 to the Pi and it would be recommended to use keys but if you use a good password, that is enough too.

Answer (score 3):

## Using ssh to securely access your Raspbery Pi

`ssh` is a client that interacts with `ssh` servers.  OpenSSH is used on many Linux distributions to act as the server.

### Installing `openssh-server`

Really, this should already be installed.

- `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`  #debian
- `sudo pacman -S openssh`  #archlinux

---

### Set up the client

#### Creating Keys

The client will use a pair of public/private keys for authentication.  It is important that you safeguard the key.  You will provide others with your public key.

- `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096`

You will be asked what to name this keypair.  In this example, we will use `pi-rsa`, which will create `pi-rsa` and `pi-rsa.pub`.  It is important to understand that **the file without any extention is to be kept private**, while the **.pub must be given to others**.

```
[meLon@freyja] ~$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/meLon/.ssh/id_rsa): /home/meLon/.ssh/pi-rsa
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/meLon/.ssh/pi-rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/meLon/.ssh/pi-rsa.pub.
```

#### Configuring `ssh`

Next, you'll define a Host and how to connect to it (your pi).

- `vim ~/.ssh/config`

>

```
Host rpi
Hostname 192.168.1.115
User pi
PubKeyAuthentication yes
IdentityFile /home/meLon/.ssh/pi-rsa
ForwardX11 yes
IdentitiesOnly yes
ForwardAgent no
```

#### Setting up your key as your credentials

Now, you'll need to give the **public key** to the server on which you wish to authenticate.  This is done by adding the **public** key to the remote server's `authorized_keys` for the user.  It is found in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.  Each key is a single-line, and can be edited manually, or via `ssh-copy-id`.

- `ssh-copy-id -i /home/meLon/.ssh/pi-rsa.pub rpi`

Because we set up and defined `rpi` in our `~/.ssh/config` file, it will connect to the Raspberry Pi.

---

### Removing PasswordAuthentication from your server

It is recommended that you use keys to authenticate over ssh, and it is very easy to disable passwords now that you've set up your key.  Remember, this is back on the Raspberry Pi itself.

- `sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Find **PasswordAuthentication** and make sure it says:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

### Connect to your Raspberry Pi

- `ssh rpi`
- `ssh some_user@rpi`

### Send a file to your Raspberry Pi

- `scp ~/Downloads/download.iso rpi:` # To home directory
- `scp ~/Downloads/download.iso rpi:Downloads/` # To Downloads in home
- `scp ~/Downloads/download.iso rpi:/home/meLon/Downloads/`  # Full path
- `scp -r ~/Downloads/ rpi:` # Recursively send the directory

### Notes

1. Make sure you've changed the `pi` account's password.  This can be done via a terminal with `passwd`.
2. This should be good for a LAN, but if you're going to be accessing this from the Internet, you might want to learn a little more to secure your pi.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to enable secure Web or SSH access to your Raspberry Pi without port forwarding is using a relay service like https://ngrok.com/ or https://pagekite.net/ or https://yaler.net/

Comment: If I understand it correctly then these relay services need a client software running behind the firewall, which keeps a tunnel open to the relay server operated by the service provider. Incoming requests to the machine behind the firewall (i.e. requests from the public internet) are routed from this relay server to the client software running behind the firewall.

Comment: Exactly. The "client software" on the device is quite small and the initial handshake between it and the relay is transparent to the local server listening to localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I think setting up VPN may be an overkill. But it also depends on what you want to do. If you let us know what your purpose is, we may be able to help better.

With SSH I am able to do most things I want do remotely on my RPi. Just to expand on ppumkin's answer, here is a quick work flow for you (of course you may already know this but may help others):

1. Setup SSH on RPi (I recommend changing the default SSH port 22 to something else for security). We will call it ZZZZ.
2. If you have not already done so, change the username and especially password to something strong. Many RPi distros come with default usernames and passwords.
3. Restart your RPi.
4. Setup port forwarding on your router or gateway - direct the SSH port number to Raspberry Pi's internal ip address
5. If you have a domain name pointed towards your network's external IP you can use that host or use the external IP. Connect through SSH using host (domain or external IP), SSH port number, username and password. On Windows you could use PuTTY. To access files, you could do SFTP through Filezilla.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers
It’s helping me a lot
My purpose is simple. My Raspi is taking every day a video on a far away site and sending it to me via Dropbox.  It’s working well. But I wish to be able from my main place outside through internet to intervene from time to time to change certain parameters and view other snapshots taken by the Raspi.
My Raspi would be the server and my laptop and tablet the only clients. I think I don’t need OpenVpn for that. But through SSH changing the port and with strong password as you suggest will it be secure enough?

Comment: Well the best would be with SSH keys and with a strong passcode too. That in my opinion will give you the strongest protection. But I have had a just a strong password with no keys on my home server for 6 years now without any security issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be paranoid you can have 2 factor authentication using Google Authenticator app.

Read more here http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=61993

Maybe not the simplest way - but I found certificates more difficult.

I can also report that I have detected the scanners are now occasionally using user 'pi' when attempting ssh to my webserver. Unfortunately I cannot change the port number there, but I do block the source IP after two failed attempts.